# Why is one query consistently ~25ms faster than another in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

A friend wrote a query with the following condition:

```
    AND ( SELECT count(1) FROM users_alerts_status uas 
         WHERE uas.alert_id = context_alert.alert_id 
         AND   uas.user_id = 18309 
         AND   uas.status = 'read' ) = 0
```

Seeing this, I suggested we change it to:

```
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM users_alerts_status uas 
           WHERE uas.alert_id = context_alert.alert_id 
           AND   uas.user_id = 18309 
           AND   uas.status = 'read' )
```

But in testing, the first version of the query is consistently between 20 and 30ms faster (we tested after restarting the server).  Conceptually, what am I missing?

Comment: Would be useful to see the outputs of EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the two in comparison--- presumably that's how you're comparing the timings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the first one can short circuit; as soon as it sees any rows that match the criteria, it can return the count of 1. The second one needs to check every row (and it returns a row of "1" for every result), so doesn't get the speed benefit of short circuiting.

That being said, doing an EXPLAIN (or whatever your database supports) might give a better insight than my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, I'd say that your option is at least as good as the other, at least a little more elegant. I'm not sure if it should be slower or faster - and if those 25ms are relevant.
The definite answer, usually, comes by looking at the EXPLAIN output.

What Postgresql version is that? [PG 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html) is said to have some optimizations regarding NOT EXISTS